# Strange debug view showing from chrome inspect of a cordova application

Tags: google-chrome, inspect

From last few days when i want to debug my cordova application it is showing strange layout of a device which running html page. I also try to enable disable chrome://flag --> 'Composited render layer borders' but nothing change. Here is a screenshot of a chrome:inspect
[image]

Comment: Hi, I am having the same problem, did you ever manage resolve the issue? The strange thing is that it looked fine two days ago..